# How to Select By Attributes on only Field with all its chars in Capital letters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, string

Need some assistance with this situation: I have a polygon feature class with a **string Field**. It has mixed values like: "PARIS" - "LISBON" - "london" - "luxemburg" - "Athens".

In this example, I'd only want to SELECT: *PARIS* and *LISBON*. How could be the statement? I think it is something with UPPER ("Name_Field") within the Select By Attributes text box... but I don`t know.

Comment: Please answer your question in the answer section.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried @artwork21.I didn't have permission.

Answer (score 4):

This was the statement that provided me with a solution:

```
UPPER( "Field_Name" ) LIKE  "Field_Name"
```